# how to change auto generated id in mosquitto?

Tags: node-red, mosquitto

I had been successfully install **MOSQUITTO Broker** on my Raspberry Pi 2 and I send messages between nord red and mosquitto what I want is to change the client id generated by the broker after a client connect here is my conf file:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile
allow_anonymous false
#clientid_prefixes target-
max_keepalive 60
allow_zero_length_clientid true
auto_id_prefix  auto- target-
```

After Reading the [Documentation](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) They Said that you only need to just add to conf file clientid_prefixes *prefix* but that did not work any help?

here is the logs of broker:

```
Sending CONNACK to mqtt_f58c6e8c.3778b (0, 0)
1587044259: Received SUBSCRIBE from mqtt_f58c6e8c.3778b
1587044259: xxxxx/# (QoS 2)
1587044259:mqtt_f58c6e8c.3778b  // this need to be changed // 
1587044259: Sending SUBACK to mqtt_f58c6e8c.3778b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That clientID is not being generated by the broker, it is being generated by the MQTTjs library used by Node-RED for it's MQTT nodes.

The part after the `_` is going to be the Node-RED internal node id for the broker config node.

You can set the clientID under the broker config where you set the broker's IP address.

`auto_id_prefix` is only used when the broker is generating a clientID for clients that have not sent one with the connect packet (this is when `allow_zero_length_clientid` is also true). In this case it is not happening because Node-RED is always going to sent a clientID.

The `clientid_prefixes` setting will restrict access to only clients that have the matching prefix. So if you set this to `clientid_prefixes target-` you will have to manually set a clientID in Node-RED that has the `target-` prefix for it to be able to connect.

Comment: and what about restricting cliendIDs #clientid_prefixes target_ so if i put whatever the client id is the node-red connect to the broker the node-red should not do that

Comment: so if i send a cliend id different then targe- the node-red should not connect is that what you are trying to say ?

Comment: Yes, it's working just like that when I test it locally.

Comment: then why my node-red always connected even with wrong clientID? i know i am asking too much but i am new mosquitto and mqtt protocol

Comment: Because it's commented out in the config you've shown here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211816/discussion-between-zakaria-darwish-and-hardillb).